# Is it safe for babies to use any kind of battery for a wearable project?

Tags: batteries

I want to make a wearable project for babies, is the commercial batteries safe for babies? Lithium Battery or Alkaline AA Battery? or can be risk to use them? the current provide by the batteries can harm the baby?

Comment: We are not lawyers. Clothes, toys, and projects for children have very strict safety and fire standards.

Comment: zinc-air (hearing aid) batteries such as A10 perhaps, though the swallow hazard is an issue.

Comment: Didn't ask for a lawyer advice, Thanks MarkU I will check it!

Comment: Your question's lack of detail left you open for lawyer advice so either add a whole lot of technical detail (about battery type and methods of protection) or accept the liklihood that this question will be closed. Xmas is over.

Comment: Is this a lawyer forum? if not, there is no point for asking that kind of advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, just be careful with the design. Make sure all the connections are adequately insulated and robust enough to handle the loads. Use an enclosure that requires tools to open, nothing that could be opened by hand alone. Leave overhead so you're not drawing the battery close to it's operating limits. This will help insure it doesn't overheat.